# Using Angularjs binding with Backbone-style objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, angularjs, parse-platform

I am working on an app using a Parse.com back end and an Angularjs front end. Parse uses Backbone-style objects with getters and setters, e.g. I can't just connect an object property to a text field with `ng-model="object.property"`. The properties are available in the object.attributes property, but I believe that's not meant to be set to directly. For now, I'm doing something like (assuming keys is a list of the property names):

```
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  object[keys[i]] = object.get(keys[i]);
}
```

Then let things happen to the object in Angular, and then:

```
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  object.set(keys[i], object[keys[i]]);
}
object.save();
```

Can anyone think of a better way to handle this?

Comment: I didn't really follow your question. I think you should probably separate local data binding from server data binding. That is, put your model sync stuff in a service which can be sync'd when necessary. Parse.com also has a [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest) would play swimmingly with AngularJS.

Comment: Hmm, yeah using the REST api might also be good because it would make it much easier to test and to swap out another back end in the future if I wanted to. I like the convenience of authentication with the js api, but I could use the js api for authentication only and REST for CRUD operations, then maybe in the future not use the js api at all...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess with the Model#set method because it involves internal stuff, but I can't think of anything wrong using model.attributes instead of Model#get if it'd be so much easier for you.
That said, I'd think you'd prefer those:

```
// Model#get
myModel.toJSON(); // returns a clone of model.attributes, cool eh?

// Model#set
myModel.set(JSON); // Model#get doesn't support it, but you can set several attributes at the same time
```

Those 2 methods do what you wanted, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ParseSDK and use this AngularJS module instead : https://github.com/jimrhoskins/angular-parse

> There are a few things that are not ideal about the
>   existing Parse JavaScript API in AngularJS. The existing API is
>   modeled after Backbone Models and the main problem is setters are used
>   instead of object properties. instance.set('property', 'value')
>   doesn't really fit well with things like ng-model
>
> Instead, angular-parse is based loosely on Spine Models where
>   properties directly defined on the object are used. To facilitate
>   this, when defining a model, it is "configured" by supplying the class
>   name (as defined in Parse) as well as which properties are part of
>   that class.
>
> Angular-parse also uses promises for any methods making network calls.